# Sympy: solve assuming variable is positive

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I would like to solve an equation assuming the variable is positive. I try to use `assuming` construction like

```
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q, ask
from sympy.abc import x

with assuming(Q.positive(x)):
  sol = solve(Eq(x**2, 4))
  print(sol)
```

But such a construction still gives two roots: `[-2,2]`. On the other hand if I initially declare variable `x` as `x = symbols('x', positive=True)` the function `solve` works fine. How actually `assuming` works?

Comment: The `solve` function only uses the core assumptions like `positive=True`. The new assumptions system is not really used anywhere in sympy itself yet.

Comment: Ok, `assuming` is not compatible with another part of `sympy` right now. I am a bit confused about the cases: 1. I would like to use symbols from `sympy.abc` as `real` variables, but by default all of them are `complex`. 2. I would like to `sympy.sympify` a string expression containing variables. All of these variables are also assumed complex. How to deal with these?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the whole idea of the `assuming` function, let's take a look at some points:

- **Queries**:

  I like to interpret `Q` ([assumption keys](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html) this page is about Predicates) as *"**Q**uery"* or *"**Q**uestion"*.
  The `Q` attribute provides a lot of predicates that you can use to test boolean values and expressions. So it works indeed like question and answer.

  - `Q.predicate(boolean)` is for generating a `Predicate` object that can be evaluated with
    `True`, `False` and `None`.
  - `ask(boolean)` provides the answer for the query (may be a `Predicate` object or other boolean).

---

- **The `assuming` function itself**:

  When you use the `with` statement and the `assuming` function, you are creating a context for querying. This means you are passing arguments to `assuming` and using them inside the body of the `with` statement.

  It is comparable to creating a virtual environment, different from the base environment. There you can use the values passed to `assuming` as they were axioms, literally assuming that they are `True`.

  Another important point is that when you create a query instantiating an object of `Q`, it is intuitively intended to use the `ask` function to determine the value of the `Predicate` object or expression.

---

Also, you may find an interesting reading about the old and new assumptions of SymPy [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/assumptions.html) (this page is about the old assumptions).

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Speaking as the author f the linked docs page maybe a similar page should be added that explains the new assumptions.

Comment: Hello @OscarBenjamin, thanks for your suggestion!!! Feel free to edit this post too! I strongly believe you know this topic better than I do haha. If you agree, we could improve this post together with a new link pointed to the new assumptions as you said.

Comment: I think you've answered this pretty well but perhaps the main point is just that you shouldn't expect any arbitrary function like `solve` to be affected by the new assumptions. The `assuming` function  only affects calls to `ask` and pretty much nothing in the SymPy codebase uses `ask` for anything.